# How to check if EditText is Blank?

Tags: android, button, android-edittext

I have **1 EditText** in android for users to input and **one button**.
on clicking button it takes input from editText and perform some operation However **I don't want to execute onClick method if EditText is Empty**?? How to achieve this?

Comment: try to put if(EditText.getText.ToString().equals() == ""){//do nothing}else{//yourcounting code}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

before doing every thing check if edittext has text like this:

```
EditText dAmnt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
if(!dAmnt.getText().toString().equalIgnoreCase("")){
     // do your work  (also add Integer.parseInt to try / catch if user enter text you put zero or... istead that)
}else{
  //user enter nothing in edittext
}
```

Comment: thanx bro its works for me...i have one more question what can i do to store counters value permanently i mean what to do so that destroying activity does not affect my counter...

Comment: you can save number in sharedPreferences

Answer (score 1):

Instead of checking "dAmnt.getText()!= null " try to implement this "!dAmnt.getText().toString().isEmpty() " as dAmnt.getText() wont return null as you have got the id of view it wont return null it returns the string value as empty. So check for whether the string you go is empty or not.